# How are display names determined for mail that comes from outside Exchange?

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, outlook

I've found lots of articles explaining how Exchange gets display names out of LDAP, etc., but not a lot about what it does when mail isn't coming from within the Exchange environment.

When we've sent out mail in the past from our servers, it's always been the case that we see the from label appear underneath the subject line in the list of emails, but we don't see it in the message viewing pane, e.g.:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XluC.jpg

I had always assumed this was just the way Exchange worked and there wasn't really anything to be done about it. I recently had someone ask about it and went to get them a screenshot from a big email sender (in this case Amazon) to demonstrate. Surprisingly, they seem to have found a way to display it in the message viewing pane (albeit along with the sending address):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv4Gd.jpg

Does anyone know how they're accomplishing this? I tried pulling out the source from Outlook but the From: header for theirs appears to be configured the same as mine...

Answer (score 3):

I actually ended up getting an answer to this on my own - Outlook determines this from the Sender header rather than the mail-from header (which in our case didn't have the display name attached). We're going to be adjusting this internally.